# Why is my android 11 phone clock slowing down until reboot

Tags: android

recently while commuting, I noticed that my phone is slow by few minutes and I missed a train because of it, since then I have been paying close attention to the clock on the phone vs clock on my laptop both provided by network.

Even when the phone's time is provided by the network, the slowing down happens until I reboot it, and it's really driving me crazy.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Off-topic on StackOverflow. Probably appropriate for [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) but you aren't saying which Android device (make/model/model number), is the device rooted or not, and which carrier are you using.